# Invoking a remote Camel through RMI

Tags: java, rmi, apache-camel

I have two instances of the same Camel-using web application deployed on two separate servers.
Only instance A will receive certain external event notifications. I need to somehow inform instance B of this.

So far, I tried registering the route as follows:

```
RmiEndpoint endpoint= (RmiEndpoint) endpoint("rmi://remotehost:1199/foo");
endpoint.setRemoteInterfaces(Junki.class);
from(endpoint).to("bean:bar");
```

and another route like this:

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:rmi"/>
    <to uri="rmi://remotehost:1199/foo"/>
</route>
```

hoping that this will allow to invoke a method on bean *bar* on the remote server by sending messages to the local *direct:rmi*. when I try running this, I get no exceptions, but no effect either. The Camel examples on the site are horrible, referring to inexistent URI schemas and showing everything completely out of context, so I couldn't learn much from there. Yet, the little that they do explain is done exactly as above.